# Problem with a parametrized test with cypress.io

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests

I want want to start a parametrized dynamic test with cypress.io. The parameters for this are in a file called params.
In before the variable params get the parameters from the file, but the forEach loop loops over the intial value 1 and 2. Can anbody give me an hint to solve the problem?

```
describe('Suite', () => {

    let params=[1,2];

    before(() =>{

        cy.readFile('cypress\\fixtures\\params.txt').then( data=> {

            params = data;
            params= params.replace(/(\r\n)/gm, "\t");
            params = params.split('\t');
            cy.log(params);
          })
    })

    params.forEach( param  =>{

        it('Testing with '+param+':', ()=>{

            ...
        })

    });

})
```

Answer (score 4):

How bout this:
In fixtures params.json file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Test 1",
    "something": "Some text"
  },
  {
    "name": "Test 2",
    "something": "Some other text"
  }
]
```

And in integration test.spec.js file:

```
const params = require('../fixtures/params.json');

params.forEach((test) => {
    it(test.name, () => {
        cy.log(test.something);
    });
});
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for this, this saves me so much repeating of testcode. I am happy that I found this answer. So again, many thanks!!